# Interfaces - is it worth to force them in that case?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I couldn't find any answer to my question so I'm here.

I'm trying to create my first game, a farm game. There are a lot of things which are controlled by player with cursor, for example to dynamically changing a game mode (part of code of "plowed field controller" script below):

```
    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() || !buildManager.isModeFlexible()) return;

        if (IsPlowed)
        {
            if (PlantGO || !buildManager.PlantItem) return;

            buildManager.BuildMode = BuildMode.Plant_Mode;
        }
        else
        {
            buildManager.BuildMode = BuildMode.Plow_Mode;
        }
    }
```

Or for clicked event:

```
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) return;

        if (buildManager.BuildMode == BuildMode.Dig_Mode) Dig();
        else if (buildManager.BuildMode == BuildMode.Plant_Mode) AssignTask(TaskType.PlantTask);
        else if (buildManager.BuildMode == BuildMode.Plow_Mode) AssignTask(TaskType.PlowTask);
    }
```

There are a few scipts for controlling collectable objects, plantable objects, etc. Currently I'm not using interfaces(and I haven't used them a lot) but I thought about it and it's the question connected with just interfaces.

Is it worth to use interfaces in this case? As I said, there are no many scripts to control gameobjects at least until now(for example for collect there will be only plant/tree/animal) but they are mouse events mainly. But it would be really handy if i could do only one script to control all OnMouseDown/Up/... events from other objects. Also I don't know will I make more similar scripts in the future. But there are mouse events and I quess it's impossible to catch OnMouseDown globally(executing in one script for every object).
I know it's possible to do that in Update method, but I'm not sure is it really optimalizated solution(my simple test of it):

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) return;

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                GameObject collider = hit.collider.gameObject;
                if (buildManager.BuildMode == BuildMode.Dig_Mode) DigMode(collider);
                else if (buildManager.BuildMode == BuildMode.Plant_Mode) PlantMode(collider);
                else if (buildManager.BuildMode == BuildMode.Collect_Mode) CollectMode(collider);
                else if (buildManager.BuildMode == BuildMode.Plow_Mode) PlowMode(collider);
            }
        }
    }

    void DigMode(GameObject go)
    {
        IDiggable iDiggable = go.GetComponent<IDiggable>();
        if (iDiggable == null) return;

        iDiggable.Dig();
    }

    ...
```

And it's just a solution for OnMouseUp event. What if I want to do some with OnMouseEnter event? In my opinion it's no sense to do this in that case, because I would need to check something every frame.

So I'm asking you "Is it worth to force interfaces in that case, when I want to checking mouse events? Or is it only for 'making good code' but in this case it's totally meaningless" Maybe there is a global event for OnMouseEvent about which I was talking before and I'm not aware of. But it should simple solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of these GameObjects (plants,trees,animals) needs the same MouseUp/MouseDown functions why dont you just inherit **Plant,Tree,Animal** class from a lets say **GonnaBePlanted** class which is inherited by MonoBehaviour itself.

so this way you can simply adjust the MouseUp/Down event in the **GonnaBePlanted** class and handle different properties for say **Animal** in its own class yet you have access to all MonoBehaviour properties since **GonnaBePlanted** is inherited from it !

Comment: You are right. I thought about that and I will make base class for these three classes. But they work in the similar way (I want to add growing system, etc.).
What if I would like to do class which will work in totally different way but still possible to collectable? Should I just copy that feature to the class or it can be done in smarter way. It's just an example because that class can inherit from other base class and then it can't inherit from 2 classes.

Comment: @Hunty i dont get it , its a global feature between all of these Collectable classes why dont you just implement it in **GonnaBePlanted** class ?! with this structure you can have global functionality between all of them happen in **GonnaBePlanted** and manage self functionalities in theyr own classes.

Comment: @Hunty You might wanna check abstract classes too